# Passing an object to constructor then calling functions using bind

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a function to an object through the constructor in order to use it inside the class using bind. Here is my code.

gameManager.js

```
    var GameManager = function() {

        this.inputManager = new InputManager(   this.moveRight.bind(this), this.moveDown.bind(this),
                                            this.moveLeft.bind(this), this.moveUp.bind(this));
    }

GameManager.prototype.moveLeft = function () {
    ...
}
```

inputManager.js

```
var InputManager = function(moveRight, moveDown, moveLeft, moveUp) {

    this.moveRight = moveRight
    this.moveDown = moveDown
    this.moveLeft = moveLeft
    this.moveUp = moveUp
}
```

then I want to be able to call one of the "move" functions in InputManager

```
InputManager.prototype.doKeyDown = function (e) {

    if ( (e.keyCode === 65) || (e.keyCode === 37)) { //A, left arrow
     console.log(this.moveLeft)   
     this.moveLeft()
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: this.moveLeft is not a function.` 
When printing I get undefined.
What am I doing wrong, or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't `GameManager.prototype.moveRight` include `moveLeft` and not `moveRight`?

Comment: Sorry, I have just posted one of them, they look similar though

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/k9rh211z/ What's different?

Comment: So what is it? Can you log the value of `this.moveLeft` to the console to see what it _actually_ is?

Comment: Also, can you provide us more context of _where_ you are calling the `this.moveLeft` function?

Comment: When you call `this.moveLeft` in `InputManager`, what do you want it to use as the context for `this`?

Comment: @somethinghere Updated my question. @ user3297291 I cant tell the difference :/

Comment: If you're attaching your method as an event listener, there might be an additional `bind` going on behind the scenes (depending on how you set it up). jQuery for example binds the `element` to `this` when setting up an event listener. You can make sure the `this` context is correct by using another `.bind(instance)` when you add the event method.

Comment: @Pierre It's a bit flummoxing, it all looks like it should at least work (it might throw different errors, but not `this thing is undefined`). I am wondering, though, if this duplication is useful. Why not do something like `function InputManager(forObject){ this.parent = forObject; }` and then call them using `this.forObject.moveLeft()`?

Comment: Yes it seems like its something else, thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Binding your `GameManager` methods is fine when you pass them to the input manager, but that's nothing to do with your problem. You will also need to bind your `InputManager` methods when you use them as event listeners - the problem is how `doKeyDown` is called.